# Question regarding the use of std::bind in ROS2 tutorial

Tags: c++, ros2

I am fairly new to C++ and I have a question regarding practices of std::bind. The following snippet is copied from this [tutorial on the ROS2 website](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#write-the-publisher-node). The code creates a class where the timer_ field hosts a timer that is created using `create_wall_timer()`. `creates_wall_timer()` accepts a callback object of type `CallbackT &&`. In the constructor of the class, why does the author pass the result of `std::bind(...)` as the callback to `create_timer()` instead of a direct pointer or reference to the timer_callback method?

Apologies for the long questions. I am not really good at asking these questions. Hopefully, I didn't miss too much information that you need.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

/* This example creates a subclass of Node and uses std::bind() to register a
* member function as a callback from the timer. */

class MinimalPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MinimalPublisher()
    : Node("minimal_publisher"), count_(0)
    {
      publisher_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10);
      timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
      500ms, std::bind(&MinimalPublisher::timer_callback, this));
    }

  private:
    void timer_callback()
    {
      auto message = std_msgs::msg::String();
      message.data = "Hello, world! " + std::to_string(count_++);
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", message.data.c_str());
      publisher_->publish(message);
    }
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;
    size_t count_;
};
```

Comment: we need the declaration of `create_wall_timer`. But most likely `create_wall_timer` takes a function object with no parameters and a member method has a hidden `this` parameter, that's why bind is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a pointer to a member function in isolation (unless that function is declared `static`), because it needs an instance of the [right kind of] object to be called on.

`std::bind` binds a pointer to an object (`this`, in this example) to the member function pointer (`&MinimalPublisher::timer_callback`) so that when the time comes to call the function, there is an instance of the required / desired object available.

To look at this from another (simpler) angle, consider what happens if you write:

`MinimalPublisher::timer_callback ();`

If `MinimalPublisher::timer_callback` is not a `static` function the compiler will complain, because a non-static function can only be called through a [pointer to a] `MinimalPublisher` object, so something like:

`my_minimal_publisher_object.MinimalPublisher::timer_callback ();`

or:

`my_minimal_publisher_object_pointer->MinimalPublisher::timer_callback ();`

You might like to experiment with this in your [favourite online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JqtPG8wUzY6xO6DS).

Incidentally, `std::bind` has been largely superseded by [capturing lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) these days.  So, in order to capture the required object instance (and taking my original example over at Wandbox as a starting point), [you might do](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sFhhsGCBkcz9SFH6):

```
#include <functional>

struct MyStruct
{
    void foo ();
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct s;
    std::function <void ()> f = [&s] { s.foo (); };
    // Do things with f
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that all non-static functions within a class technically have a "this" parameter? From what I read on std::bind, it populates the function with the argument provided by the user.

Comment: Yes, precisely so.  No `this` pointer, no deal.  What `std::bind` does is to wrap up into a `std::function` the member function pointer and the pointer to the object to be used as `this` when the function is called.  You can also specify further parameters if the member function signature needs them.  '`this` must then be the first parameter to `std::bind` and any others must follow (in the appropriate order).